# Django AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'select_for_update'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a simple model define in Django. I want to select an Object using django `select_for_update` method to ensure data persistence as multiple threads needs to update single row but different columns. But it is giving following error:

```
Obj = my_model.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk=1)

AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'select_for_update'
```

Please help me in solving this issue. Thanks

Comment: which version of django are you using? this is new in 1.4 (not yet released). Note that the docs default to the dev version, you can change in the bottom right

Comment: As mentioned above, this is [new in 1.4](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django/en/latest/releases/1.4.html#select-for-update-support).  You can apply a patch if you're using 1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check it out the documentation :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update

so if you`ll have to upgrade your django version to the development version!